# How to display specific cell of UICollectionView using viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am a new iOS programming. and now i am developing an app which display similar to appstore. But i have some problems which when user open the app so, i want cell of data should be display the second cell. for example, i have three cell then when user open the app the second cell should be automatically scrolled to that position.

Here is how i created header section: (programmatically)

```
/// banner section
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerCellId, for: indexPath) as! HeaderBanner

    header.sectionCategory = dashbordCell?[indexPath.item]

    return header
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 370)
    return size
}
```

Here is I created HeaderBanner

```
let dataBannerCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

    var scrollInterval: Int = 3
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return collectionView

}()

func setupViewsCell(){
    dataBannerCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false


    dataBannerCollectionView.dataSource = self
    dataBannerCollectionView.delegate = self

    dataBannerCollectionView.register(HeaderBannerDataCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: headerCellId)

    addSubview(dataBannerCollectionView)
    setupConstraintDataBannerCollectionView()



}
```

Here is behavior of HeaderBanner file.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = sectionCategory?.dataBanner?.count {

        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: headerCellId, for: indexPath) as! HeaderBannerDataCell
    cell.dataBannerCell = sectionCategory?.dataBanner![indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    print(frame.width)
    let size = CGSize(width: frame.width - 100 , height: 350)
    return size
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Banner selected")
}
```

As you can see the header section display the first cell of image. I just my app look like this when user opens the app .

Here is output of my sample app:

[image]

Here is my expectation which i want to display the middle cell of all cells.

[image]

Comment: not getting you issue please notify on screenshot

Comment: @PravinTate I just wanted when user opens the app, the cell should be scroll to the middle of all cell. "The Header Section"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the scrollToItem function of UICollectionView:

if you have three cells for example:

```
        dataBannerCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
```

Add that code in setupViewsCell() function